# data base is missing(db.sqlite3)

Tags: database

I was creating a polls app and templates in Django but some how deleted the data base while trying to sort out some errors. How do I get the database back or create a new one. It currently shows that the data base is empty. Also the file in the recycle bin shows empty.

Nothing yet. Im not sure where to start?

Comment: Restore it from your backup, and ask your colleagues not to delete it again

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, Nico. I am extremely new to all this. I will have to go and google how to restore from the backup. Thanks again.